# OnPreferenceChangeListener unreachable code

Tags: android

I'm developing my first app that add tweaks to local.prop from /data.
I use PreferenceActivity that implements OnPreferenceChangeListener.
I detect the key by findPreference.

This is the code:

```
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
    String key = preference.getKey();
    if ("first_key".equals(key) && !((CheckBoxPreference) preference).isChecked()) {
        // code
    }
    if ("second_key".equals(key) && !((CheckBoxPreference) preference).isChecked()) {
        // code
    }
}
```

Everything is ok since I add the second if (second_key). The error is "Unreachable code".
Please, help me! What I did wrong?

Comment: Which part is marked as "unreachable"?

Comment: if ("second_key".equals(key) && !((CheckBoxPreference) preference).isChecked()) {
        // code
    }
This is the unreachable code. You can see below what is in second if.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added all of the code.

This wouldn't cause the error you wrote. However there might be an error if you return before the 2nd if, which would then be unreachable.

If this is an implemented method, based on [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html), you probably want to return true at the end, so the preference is set:

```
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
    String key = preference.getKey();
    if ("first_key".equals(key) && !((CheckBoxPreference) preference).isChecked()) {
        // Do something if pref 1
    } else if ("second_key".equals(key) && !((CheckBoxPreference) preference).isChecked()) {
        // Do something if pref 2
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that you can use `else if` here because you can't have a single preference with both keys at the same time. Different preferences will make different calls to this method, considering you have set the listeners, considering you have set them.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.fast_gaming.performance;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends PreferenceActivity implements OnPreferenceChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.main);
        findPreference("enable").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        findPreference("debug.sf.nobootanimation").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        String key = preference.getKey();
        if ("enable".equals(key) && !((CheckBoxPreference) preference).isChecked()) {
            try {
                Process enable = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(enable.getOutputStream());
                outputStream.writeBytes("cd /data\n");
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.writeBytes("touch local.prop\n");
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.writeBytes("chmod 0777 local.prop\n");
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
                outputStream.flush();
                enable.waitFor();
                File file = new File("/system/bin/su");
                if (file.exists()) {
                    Log.d("Main", "This device is rooted!");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    Log.d("Main", "This device is not rooted!");
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "This device is not rooted!";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                    return false;
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            try {
                Process disable = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(disable.getOutputStream());
                outputStream.writeBytes("cd /data\n");
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.writeBytes("rm local.prop\n");
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
                outputStream.flush();
                disable.waitFor();
                File file = new File("/system/bin/su");
                if (file.exists()) {
                    Log.d("Main", "This device is rooted!");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    Log.d("Main", "This device is not rooted!");
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "This device is not rooted!";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if ("debug.sf.nobootanimation".equals(key) && !((CheckBoxPreference) preference).isChecked()) {
            try {
                Process enable1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(enable1.getOutputStream());
                outputStream.writeBytes("cd /data\n");
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.writeBytes("echo \"debug.sf.nobootanimation=1\" > local.prop\n");
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
                outputStream.flush();
                enable1.waitFor();
                File file = new File("/system/bin/su");
                if (file.exists()) {
                    Log.d("Main", "This device is rooted!");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    Log.d("Main", "This device is not rooted!");
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "This device is not rooted!";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            try {
                Process enable1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(enable1.getOutputStream());
                outputStream.writeBytes("cd /data\n");
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.writeBytes("sed '/debug..sf.nobootanimation=1/d' filename.txt\n");
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
                outputStream.flush();
                enable1.waitFor();
                File file = new File("/system/bin/su");
                if (file.exists()) {
                    Log.d("Main", "This device is rooted!");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    Log.d("Main", "This device is not rooted!");
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "This device is not rooted!";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
        } return true;
    }
}
```

This is the complete code. I made what you said, and nothing happened. Eclsipse says to me "Syntax error on token "else", delete this token", and if i remove else, again "unreachable code"...

Comment: You are doing if, else, elseif, else. That is impossible. The sequence must be if, elseif, else..